# hash tables and solving equations

Tags: python, data-structures, hashtable

Is there a way to use hash tables to find the number of integer solutions to this equation?

```
Aj^3 + Bk^3 + Cl^3 + Dm^4 + En^5 = S
```

where `A, B, C, D, E` and `S` are constants between `-1000` and `1000` (inclusive) and `j, k, l, m` and `n` are integers between `-50` and `50` (inclusive).

Comment: Say for example, the equation is 12j^3 + 34k^3 + 56l^3 + 78m^4+ 9n^5 =  10. Is there a way to use hash table to solve this problem instead of the naive way where you check for every possible 5 tuples? In the question it hints to use hash table. I don't really see a way to use hash table either for this, but since the question suggests, I assume there is a way.

Comment: Improved coding format.